# Devise sign up - how to save an attribute without having a form field for it (Rails4, devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rails-geocoder

I have a Rails app and have implemented geolocalization: with geocoder gem, I detect the ip and know which country the user is accessing pages from.

I'd like to add a 'country' attribute to the User table.

Users would come to the sign-up page and without them knowing I would detect for example they are accessing the app from Finland.

Then when they sign up in by filling in the 2 fields email & password, I would save email and password but I want to  save/store the country I get using geocoder in this column 'country'.

How can I save this 'country' attribute if I don't have the field in the form ?

Sounds easy but I only know how to save values when there actually is a form field the user fills in.

Here what I did:

/app/controllers/confirmations_controller.rb

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    if Devise.allow_insecure_sign_in_after_confirmation
      resource.update(user_country: request.location.country)
      after_sign_in_path_for(resource)      
    else
       resource.update(user_country: request.location.country)
       root_path
    end    
  end
```

What's weird is that the user is saved with everything fine (including location) on my local database. But then something must happen as I get an error page with the following error message:

```
undefined method `model_name' for TrueClass:Class
```

The whole error log

```
(0.8ms)  COMMIT
   (0.5ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (1.3ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "remember_created_at" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "users"."id" = 427  [["remember_created_at", 2014-06-24 10:52:32 UTC], ["updated_at", 2014-06-24 12:52:32 +0200]]
   (0.7ms)  COMMIT
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.9ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "last_sign_in_at" = $1, "current_sign_in_at" = $2, "last_sign_in_ip" = $3, "current_sign_in_ip" = $4, "sign_in_count" = $5, "updated_at" = $6 WHERE "users"."id" = 427  [["last_sign_in_at", 2014-06-24 10:52:32 UTC], ["current_sign_in_at", 2014-06-24 10:52:32 UTC], ["last_sign_in_ip", "24.193.83.1"], ["current_sign_in_ip", "24.193.83.1"], ["sign_in_count", 1], ["updated_at", 2014-06-24 12:52:32 +0200]]
   (0.7ms)  COMMIT
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (1.0ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE (LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('mathieu.proffit75++edaaaaaa+++@gmail.com') AND "users"."id" != 427) LIMIT 1
  SQL (1.3ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "user_country" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "users"."id" = 427  [["user_country", "United States"], ["updated_at", 2014-06-24 12:52:32 +0200]]
   (0.7ms)  COMMIT
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4984ms

NoMethodError - undefined method `model_name' for TrueClass:Class:
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/model_naming.rb:9:in `model_name_from_record_or_class'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb:182:in `build_named_route_call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb:120:in `polymorphic_url'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb:159:in `url_for'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:68:in `_process_options'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:202:in `_process_options'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:119:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:33:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:26:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:97:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
  activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
  /home/mreisner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/benchmark.rb:296:in `realtime'
  activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  activerecord (4.0.5) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:233:in `default_render'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:161:in `to_html'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:154:in `respond'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:147:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:330:in `respond_with'
  devise (3.2.4) app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:20:in `create'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:483:in `_run__1192109421260337467__process_action__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.0.5) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:44:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:674:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.5) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.5) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.5) lib/active_record/migration.rb:373:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__3240580690818246217__call__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  quiet_assets (1.0.2) lib/quiet_assets.rb:18:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.0.5) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.5) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /home/mreisner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /home/mreisner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /home/mreisner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably try to catch the user after they sign up.  You can read more on how to do it in the docs  [Devise: How to Redirect after Registration](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-%28registration%29)

Override the Devise Registration Controller with something like this:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    resource.update(location: request.location)
    root_path
  end
end
```

That is untested code but should get you in the right direction.  The second line of the method returns a redirect to the `root_path` after signup which you might want to change.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I edited my post: i think you've put me in the right direction but I am still getting an error.

Comment: Do you think you could spot what's wrong cause i have been spending hours to no result ?

Comment: Hard to know without seeing the code.  Looks like a classic Devise error that stackoverflow might be able to help you with.  Probably something in the controller is missing.

Comment: that's what i think too, but nowhere can i find people with the same error or on devise github wikis... weird. i have created a dedicated question for it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24418553/undefined-method-model-name-for-trueclassclass-for-deviseconfirmations-rails

Comment: hi Bryan, actaully what you adviced did work!!! the erro was coming because I had also put sth conflicting with it on my Confirmationscontroller. I launched a bounty in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24418553/undefined-method-model-name-for-trueclassclass-for-deviseconfirmations-rails so if you just put a message there, i'll be able to attribute you the 50points. only fair as it's your solution that was right. Please do it fast as i leave for holidays with no internet tomorrow:)